# Gradle dependsOn non gradle project

Tags: java, gradle

I have a number of gradle projects with a multi-project build stucture.

I use gradle build cache on our buildserver to only run tests in projects with changes or projects which dependsOn projects with changes. This works great and saves a lot of build time.

The problem is:
Gradle projectA depends on a non gradle projectB, and I don't know how to set this dependency.
projectB produces a docker used by projectA, and if an error is introduced in projectB, the tests in projectA doesn't run and the error goes into production.

So the question is how do you make a gradle "dependsOn" for any change in a non gradle project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is probably to use [task inputs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskInputs.html). However, inputs can currently only be directories, files and properties. This means you will have to find a way to put give the information on the Docker image to Gradle using one of those types.

For example, maybe you can make the project that builds the Docker image also output a file containing a version number or a hash. Then declare it as an input:

```
task myProjectATask() {
  inputs.file("$projectDir/docker-version.txt").withPropertyName("dockerVersion")
  // ...
}
```